# Using variable outside of try catch block (Java)

Tags: java, file, declaration

I have a variable that I have delared before a try catch block to make sure I can access it outside of the block

```
/*
        Try to get a list of all files.
         */

        List<String> result; 
        try( Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get("data"))){
            List<String> result = walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .map(x -> x.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            List<String> result = null;
        }


        ListIterator iter = result.listiterator() // cannot resolve symbol
```

when I take the original declaration out, I get a cannot resolve symbol error. 
When I keep it in I get a variable already declared error.

What would be the best way to structure this to use the variable outside of the try except clause?

Comment: Jist remove the declaration in the try block, only assign it to the already declared variable: `try(...){ result = ...`

Comment: replace `List<String> result` with `result` in the try catch

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805813/what-is-the-scope-of-a-variable-defined-inside-java-try-block-why-it-is-not-acc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the compilation error, declare the `result` variable only before the try-catch block:

```
List<String> result; 
try( Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get("data"))){
    result = walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .map(x -> x.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    result = null;
}
```

However, note that accessing the `result` variable after the try-catch block (your `result.listiterator()` statement) without checking that it's not null may throw a `NullPointerException`.

You should be asking yourself why you are catching any exception and expecting everything to work fine.